# How do you access a c:forEach loop value from a scriptlet?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

When I try to access `wrap.myUtilDate` I get an error:

```
`wrap.myUtilDate` cannot be resolved to a type
```

Can `c:forEach` loop values be accessed from a scriptlet?

```
<c:forEach items="${myWraps}" var="wrap" varStatus="status">

    <%

    java.util.Date myUtilDate = wrap.myUtilDate;
    org.joda.time.DateTime myJodaDate = new org.joda.time.DateTime(myUtilDate);

    %>

    <td><joda:format value="${myJodaDate}" style="LL"/></td>

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Try declaring the variable before the loop.

Answer (score 3):

I think JSTL keeps the variables in either `page` or `pageContext` implicit objects. Just try both of them to be sure.

```
java.util.Date myUtilDate = ((MyWrap) pageContext.getAttribute("wrap")).myUtilDate;
```

Answer (score -2):

If u get myWraps from the request, make like this

```
  <c:forEach items="${requestScope.myWraps}" var="wrap" varStatus="status">

<%

java.util.Date myUtilDate = wrap.myUtilDate;
org.joda.time.DateTime myJodaDate = new org.joda.time.DateTime(myUtilDate);

%>

<td><joda:format value="${myJodaDate}" style="LL"/></td>
```

Comment: I don't think this code will work if you don't add pageContext.setAttribute("myJodaDate", myJodaDate); before closing the scriptlet